# User keyboard interaction: a view or an event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working with a Backbone app and I have a 'philosophical' question:

When a certain key is pressed, the user will be taken to another page/view, this is to happen globally across the app, for example, wherever you are if you press H you will be taken to the Help page/view.

My question is: should this be a view or an event? Should I create a new view that does this logic or extend Backbone global events (in the main.js)?

The issue is: are user interactions events or views, or it depends?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keypress event and then redirect...

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an example for him.